# Automating Unzip

Tags: automation, zip

I would like to know if it's possible, or if a program exists that "watches" a folder for .zip files, and automatically unzips them and deletes the original.zip.

Sure I can download a file.zip, but why do I have to go through the extra step of manually unzipping it. Surely this is what computers are for, no?

Windows 7 is what I'm using, so please keep it to that.

Comment: And which operating system are you using?

Comment: Windows 7, updated the Q. Thanks for that Matt

Answer (score 1):

For the automatic rules based running of processes, [belvedere](http://lifehacker.com/#!341950/belvedere-automates-your-self+cleaning-pc) might help - however - it will open the file with whatever's the default handler for the application - so it depends on how your system reacts to it.